# How is it shown that only one actor can access an extending use case?

Tags: uml, use-case

- Use Case A is extended by Use Case B.
- Use Case A can be done by Actor X and Actor Y.

How can I show that Use Case B is accessible **only** to Actor X and **not** Y?

For example, in an e-shop:

- "Find Product" is extended by "Add to wishlist".
- "Find Product" can be done by both a Registered and a Non-Registered Actor.

However, "Add to wishlist" use case can only be done by a Registered Actor.

Comment: That's quite an interesting question. Can you give a bit more specific example where such indication would be needed? It might be that you completely have to redesign something rather than change this single indication.

Comment: @Ister, I have editted the description in order to provide a specific example.

Answer (score 2):

Simply add a constraint like `{can only be performed by Actor X}` to the use case in question.